# Chai-as-promised not extracting text value

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, chai

I have a simple page object method :

```
page.prototype.copyLink = function() {
  this.visit("https://myWebsite.com");
  this.login(); // once logged in, presented with list of elements
  return {
    firstCampaign: this.find('#el-1').getText(), //returns a promise
    secondCampaign: this.find('#el-2).getText() // returns a promise
  }
}

module.exports = page;
```

Using `Jest` and `chai-as-promised` I test that the text in each `#el` is the same:

```
var page = require("./page");

it("Export link icon should link to export html page", function(){
   var copyLink =  page.copyLink();
   return copyLink.firstCampaign.should.eventually.equal(copyLink.secondCampaign);
});
```

For some reason, chai successfully extracts the text from `firstCampaign`, but not `secondCampaign` So I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: expected '##TEST STRING##' to equal { Object (flow_, stack_, ...) }

      at getBasePromise.then.then.newArgs (node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:302:22)
      at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1384:14)
      at TaskQueue.execute_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3092:14)
      at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3075:27)
      at asyncRun (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2935:27)
      at node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
          at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Why isn't chai extracting the text from the second promise?

Answer (score 0):

Your code wait only the first promise before the equal comparison.

You need wait the execution of [all promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise/all)

```
var copyLink =  page.copyLink();
var actual;
return Promise.all([copyLink.firstCampaign, copyLink.secondCampaign]).then(results => results[0].should.equal(results[1])).should.be.fulfilled;
```